# Jquery function reset when ever document reloads

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Whenever the page where i put my jquery navigation function refreshes it will reset the jquery function, making my navigation box to hide instead of showing when i click on it.
someone told me that i should use javascript cookies.., i dont know much about it.

here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".about").on("click",function(){              
            $(".nav").show();
            $(".menu1 li a").show();
            $(".menu2 li a").hide();
            $(".menu3 li a").hide();
            $(".menu4 li a").hide();
        });

        $(".cord").on("click",function(){
            $(".menu1 li a").hide();
            $(".menu3 li a").hide();
            $(".menu4 li a").hide();
            $(".nav").show();
            $(".menu2 li a").show();
        })

</script>
```

Comment: yes you should use cookies. what have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps a [jQuery cookie tutorial](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery+cookie+tutorial&oq=jquery+cookie+tutorial&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would help? (The third Google result is specifically about retaining the interface state.)

Answer (score 0):

Download [**jQuery.Cookies**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) first.

Use it as below.

`Javascript` file use it as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
        if (checkCookie != "")
        {
            $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').next().show();
        }
        $('#nav > li > a').click(function()
        {
            var navIndex = $('#nav > li > a').index(this);
            $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            if ($(this).next().is(":visible"))
            {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            }
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });

</script>
```

I just giving explanation regarding how you can do this.

There is more better ways to use it.

[**More Help**](http://www.flipflops.org/2008/01/19/a-simple-jquery-menu-with-persistence-using-cookies/)

Comment: Bro, it didnt work.., i have try it.. can you use session for it to make it work pls.. drop session code for it.. Thanks

Comment: you can do it accordigly just replace cookies code with session using jQuery.Session plugin